# text() returning children text as well

Tags: text, return, innerhtml

http://jsfiddle.net/Lc5gdvge/

In the fiddle above, I've showcased how `text()`, returns elements text and childrens' as well. How do I avoid this and only make it return "outerdiv"?

NOTE: Just click the blue container to call function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.outerdiv').click(function() {
        var htmlstring = $(this).text();
        alert(htmlstring);
    })
});
```

NOTE 2: This has to be without the use of ID selector.

Answer (score 0):

To get the text of only the `.outerDiv` and not the children elements, use the following code :

```
$(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

What this does is, it clones the element, removes all the children tags, and goes back to the selected tag and gets the text.

The final code should look like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.outerdiv').click(function () {
    var htmlstring = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
    alert(htmlstring);

  });
});
```

Comment: This returns nothing though.

Comment: Uhm, it does work. I tried it on my own code. I edited the code and used this instead of .outerDiv. Try now.